# How to create product url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a URL consist of the shop URL + slug (from database) but I'm not sure how to combine these two into one so each product linked to their own individual page.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/nmd_r1shoes

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/shop','ShopController@index')->name('shop.index');
```

**views/best-sellers.php**

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="height: 20rem;">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach($products_sa as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a href="{{route('shop.index').$product->slug)}}">
                <img src="{{asset('/img/'.$product->photo)}}" alt="Image" style="width: 250px; height:250px;" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <p>{{$product->name}}</p>
            <p><strong>$ {{$product->price}}</strong></p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
    <!--.row-->
</div>
```

Comment: is it okay if the slug is the ID: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/1234`?

Comment: Yeah anything you can pass as slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change route as

```
 Route::get('/shop/{slug}','ShopController@index')->name('shop.index');
```

Change your view call as

```
 <a href="{{route('shop.index',$product->slug)}}">
 <img src="{{asset('/img/'.$product->photo)}}" alt="Image" style="width: 250px; height:250px;" class="img-responsive">

 </a>
```

Controller function get the slug as

```
public function index(Request $request,$slug)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of different options here.

The most basic would just be to accept the slug as a URL parameter and then resolve this in your controller to the product.

```
routes/web.php

Route::get('/shop/{slug}', 'ShopController@show');
```

```
app/Http/Controllers/ShopController.php

public function show(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    // ... whatever else you need to do and return the view
}
```

Going further than this, you could use [explicit route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) to use a custom parameter that would always resolve the product by slug; essentially abstracting the logic of querying for the product into the explicit route binding.

If you're asking a question like this though, I'd stick with the first approach.

Comment: what should I put inside href tag

Comment: @ShaifulRizalShaharudin you would do `href=“{{ ‘/shop/‘ . $product->slug }}”` you could also look into named routes to make this easier.